# Excel protect and unprotect workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that contains several (lookup) tabs that I don't want any users to be able to unhide. However, there is one tab that contains admin info that I would like admin users to be able to see.  I have a button and macro that prompts for an admin password before unhiding this tab, but if I protect the workbook structure (so that hidden tabs are not accessible for other users) the vba fails.  Is there no way to protect/unprotect the workbook from within the admin macro? I have tried various combinations of `ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect`, `ActiveWorkbook.Protect` and `ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure` to no avail - both within the admin macro and WorkbookOpen.  The error msg I most commonly encounter is "Can't assign to read-only property" even after having `ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect` at the top of my code. Does anyone know how to work around this?  I don't really want to have to leave all tabs open to being unhidden with a second password on the Admin worksheet itself - clumsy!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of protecting the whole workbook, set the `Visible` property of the sheets you want to hide to `xlSheetVeryHidden` - you can do this manually in the properties window of the VBA editor. Now those sheets won't show up in the `Unhide…` dialog. Your macro could swap the visibility of your admin-only sheet from `xlSheetVeryHidden` to `xlSheetVisible` and back.

By itself this doesn't protect your workbook from a user who knows how to access the VBA editor and properties, but if you need to do that there seem to be a lot of answers to a quick web search - it may depend on your version of Excel.

Comment: Thanks very much - fastest fix ever! :)

Comment: You're welcome! See my added info about the VBA editor though.

Comment: Noted, thanks.  I don't anticipate that most of my client's users even know how to open dev, let alone play with it, though. Even if they do, we'll keep a working copy in our system, anyway :)